# How to link against android system v8?

Tags: android, webview, android-ndk, v8, embedded-v8

The project i'm working uses v8 JavaScript Engine. We embed v8 right in our native library (libfoo-jni.so) to have full control over v8 engine. However it makes file size too large for some apps so we're asked to use system v8. I was unable to find v8 headers in NDK's `platforms/android-Z/arch-arm/usr/include`.

Is there any possibility to link against system V8 that is used for android `WebView` behind the scene? It should work without rooting and not for android devices manufacturers who have access to android platform on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not supported.

On older versions, it might be possible to do even though it's not officially supported, but in recent Android versions, the platform will refuse to load external libraries except for those that are supported. (See [Android 7.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk) for more details.)

In addition to that, there are no guarantees for the API/ABI of the bundled javascript engine - in older versions the platform could even be built with either v8 or JavaScriptCore. Any device manufacturer could be using a different, modified version.

Comment: could you please provide a link to "the platform will refuse to load external libraries except for those that are supported" (NDK release notes or Google developers blog post) to know the limitation exactly?

Comment: Updated the post with a link to the relevant docs explaining that issue.

Comment: thanks, i've accepted your answer. However, if there are any tricks, feel free to share the solution with us here (even if it works with some limitations like android version)

Comment: Any "tricks" you use here are just going to make your app unreliable. The reason linking to system libraries is not allowed is because they are not guaranteed to be ABI stable or even exist from device to device.

Comment: Yeah. I've used tricks like those on older platforms to overcome some limitations, but with extreme caution, and always with the intention that they're temporary hacks, not a longterm solution.